# ARCore augmented images without sceneform

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to create an app similar to [quiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.puteko.colarmix&hl=en) for Android. That is i need to recognize the sketch from a color book and place a 3d model with simple animation on top of it. I was planing to use ARCore but most of the tutorials use scenefoam which is now deprecated and saw some suggestions that I should use Filament directly. I would like to be pointed to resources and tutorials that i need to go over in order to be able implement the basic features of the app (recognize a 2d image and place a 3d animated model on it without using scenefoam).